# How to use dynamic routes in Reactjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working with Reactjs and right now i am trying to use "dynamic routes",
Right now i am working in "component file" (src/components/home/Myarticle.js) and here is my current code

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const res = await axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments");
            console.log("RES", res.data);
            setUsers(res.data);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);
      return (
        <div>
            <h1>Dynamic Routingdd</h1>
                {users.map((user) => {
                return (
                    <div key={user.id}>
                        Click on the id to see the details :
                        <NavLink to={"/user/" + user.id}> {user.id}</NavLink>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
```

And here is my "User.js"(root) but i am getting "404 error" and url redirect to "http://localhost:3001/404",Where i am wrong ?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, withRouter } from "react-router";
import axios from "axios";

const User = (props) => {
    const params = useParams();
    const [users, setUsers] = useState({});
    console.log(params);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const res = await axios(
                `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/${params.id}`
            );
            console.log("INDI", res.data);
            setUsers(res.data);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    return (
        <div style={{ width: "80%", margin: "0 auto" }}>
            <div
                style={{
                    margin: "20px",
                    marginRight: "auto",
                    borderRadius: "20px",
                    border: "2px solid #000",
                    width: "50%",
                    padding: "10px",
                }}
            >
                <h1>Post Id : {users.postId ? users.postId : "Loading . . . . "}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default User;
```

Here is my "routes file" (in src/routes/index.js)

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
import { Navigate, useRoutes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
// layouts
import Layout from "../layouts";
// components
import LoadingScreen from "../components/LoadingScreen";

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

const Loadable = (Component) => (props) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return (
    <Suspense
      fallback={<LoadingScreen isDashboard={pathname.includes("/dashboard")} />}
    >
      <Component {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default function Router() {
  return useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Layout />,
      children: [
        { element: <HomePage />, index: true },
        // { path: "privacypolicy", element: <PrivacyPage /> },
        // { path: "useofcookie", element: <UseofCookiePage /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: "*",
      children: [
        { path: "404", element: <Page404 /> },
        { path: "*", element: <Navigate to="/404" replace /> },
      ],
    },
    { path: "*", element: <Navigate to="/404" replace /> },
  ]);
}

const HomePage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/HomePage")));
const Page404 = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/Page404")));
// const PrivacyPage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/PrivacyPage")));
// const UseofCookiePage = Loadable(
//   lazy(() => import("../pages/UseofCookiePage"))
// );
```

Comment: can you show route configs as well

Comment: @cmgchess sure , let me update my question

Comment: @cmgchess question updated, share my code of config file

Comment: as i know useParams is in react-router-dom not in react-router (6.9v)

Comment: @choco what should i do now ? what is the solution for this ?

Comment: Basicly i can just suggest. And use my exp. So, for the Errors page it would be better instead of manualy specify for every routes "*" sign, use `errorElement` properyty. My suggest is delete everything in useRoutes and instead pass this:
```return useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Layout />,
      errorElement: <Page404 />,
      children: [
        { element: <HomePage />, index: true },
      ],
    },
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code is rendering links to *some* `"/user/*"` path that doesn't exist as a route to navigate to.

It seems you are just missing rendering a `Route` for that path.

Example:

```
export default function Router() {
  return useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Layout />,
      children: [
        { element: <HomePage />, index: true },
        { path: "privacypolicy", element: <PrivacyPage /> },
        { path: "useofcookie", element: <UseofCookiePage /> },
        {
          path: "user/:id", // <-- render User on reachable route
          element: <User />
        },
      ],
    },
    { path: "404", element: <Page404 /> },
    { path: "*", element: <Navigate to="/404" replace /> },
  ]);
}
```